# Access 2010: How to convert erroneous value to null or blank?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am doing a simple select query in Access 2010 using the design view. My source file is an excel worksheet that I have linked to a table in Access. I can view the source, but am not able to modify it in any way.

One of the columns in the source file can have the following error: "#NAME?"

When I see an error, I just want to read the value in as an empty string "", but when there isn't an error, I just want the value. I've researched different variations of using Nz, IIF, Switch, and IsError but haven't had any success yet.

I am trying the following code in the "Field" parameter in design view.

```
Program_Temp: IIf(IsError([Program]), "", [Program])
```

This fails because IIf evaluates both the "truepart" and the "falsepart" so even if the error is properly detected, the function will be in error because "[Program]" is still evaluated.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I would import the table, not link it, (you can save the import to assign it to a macro or something) and when new info is needed, delete the data and import new data.
a nice side-effect of this is that errors will be replaced by null. This also prevents the excel file from being locked, if that matters.

Comment: Importing the table didn't replace the erroneous cells with null. But the suggestion from @Adarsh led to my answer. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel will pass the values as string to the access.
Now you just have to use the replace the error with empty string.

`Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )`

`Replace ( Program_Temp, "#NAME?", "" )`

or

`Replace ( Program_Temp, "#NAME?", vbnull )`

Also I will suggest the same thing as @serakfalcon. Import the table, not link it, and when new info is needed, delete the data and import new data. A nice side-effect of this is that errors will be replaced by null.

Comment: Your answer led to my final solution. Program_Temp was what I was renaming the field to, so my Replace had to use Program instead. Thanks!
`Program_Temp: Replace(Nz([Program],""),"#NAME?","")`